# Signalr en webBrowser1 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, signalr

Alguien con un poco de experiencia me pueda ayudar.
Tengo una aplicacion de chat con **SignalR** en un host que en los navegadores funcional 100%

Pero quiero cargar esa aplicacion web en un control webBrowser de Visual Studio (C#) y me da error cuando se comienza a cargar,sin que yo toque nada.

El error dice :

> SignalR: No JSON parser found. Please ensure json2.js is referenced before
>   the SignalR.js file if you need to support clients without native JSON parsin support,e.g. IE<8

Pido su ayuda por favor :/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado usando la última versión de explorer, tal como se describe en este link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control ?

Answer (score 2):

WebBrowser es un IE con la versión que tengas instalada pero con el modo de Internet Explorer 7 (de compatibilidad).

Puede que te funcione lo que te dice MainMind, pero vas a depender siempre de lo que haya instalado en la máquina cliente.

Para evitar esto...yo, sinceramente, no usaría WebBrowser, mira este link (en inglés):

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Traducido literalmente:

> CefSharp le permite incrustar Chromium en aplicaciones .NET. Es un
>   contenedor .NET liviano alrededor de Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)
>   por Marshall A. Greenblatt. Alrededor del 30% de los enlaces están
>   escritos en C ++ / CLI con la mayoría del código aquí es C #. Se puede
>   usar desde C # o VB, o cualquier otro lenguaje CLR. CefSharp
>   proporciona implementaciones de control de navegador web WPF y
>   WinForms.

https://www.chromium.org/Home

Es decir, que puedes usar **chromium** para tu aplicación. 
Aquí un ejemplo para WinForms.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Si el problema es con Internet Explorer (por lo que parece) añade la siguiente cabecera para forzar a utilizar HTML estandar, a partir de ahí si aparece otro error envia el detalle:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Prueba también con otro navegador actualizado

- [Versiones IE sin soporte](https://www.welivesecurity.com/2016/01/12/microsoft-ends-support-for-old-internet-explorer-versions/)
- [X-UA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ff966528(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: El 2do enlace que agregaste no parece estar disponible.. Por otro lado, el modo de compatibilidad le dice al navegador que use la última versión que tiene disponible, pero para IE7 seguirá siendo IE7, por más que el `X-UA-Compatible` sea `IE=Edge`. ¿Cómo es que esta etiqueta podría cambiar el comportamiento que se ve en la pregunta?

Comment: Mismo problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818648/signalr-stops-working-in-ie10 y los detalles sobre la propiedad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do

Comment: Justamente, esa respuesta es del 2013, cuando tenía sentido usar `X-UA-Compatible`. Si estás copiando una respuesta, deberías poner el enlace en tu pregunta para que no sea plagio. Podés leer en el segundo enlace que comentaste recién a lo que me estoy refiriendo. Y el enlace en tu pregunta sigue apuntando a una web que no está disponible.

Comment: Corregido el enlace roto, si utilizas el objeto que te indica Jaime no dependerás de IE de cada máquina como muy bien explica, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome) la solución del meta es funcional en otros casos. Tambien puedes utilizar una versión más actualizada de JSON2. Un saludo